# Firebug gives applying the 'delete' operator to an unqualified name is deprecated

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firebug

I'm reading book about OO programming in JavaScript and get some strange behaviour:

```
function f1() {
    var a = 1;
    console.log('a in f1 function ', a);
    console.log('f2() called ', f2());
    return 'f1 return value';
}

function f2() {
    console.log('a value in f2() ', a);
    return a;
}

var a = 5;
a = 55;
var foo = 'bar';
console.log('delete a: ', delete a);
console.log(a);
console.log(f1());
console.log('delete window.f2: ', delete window.f2);
console.log(f1());
console.log('delete foo: ', delete foo);
```

Could anyone understand, why my delete VARIABLE return false (in Firefox) and strict mode display warning like:

```
SyntaxError: applying the 'delete' operator to an unqualified name is deprecated
console.log('delete foo: ', delete foo);
```

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't delete a normal variable in javascript.  You can delete a property on an object, but not a variable.  Thus, what you're trying to do isn't allowed.  If you want to free the contents of that variable (assuming there are no other references to the data it points to), you can just set the variable to `null`.

The part of the message about `unqualified` probably just refers to the fact that specifying a property would have to be more than just an unqualified name like you have.  It would have to have an object reference.

As DCoder mentions in a comment, this is a [good reference](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) for understanding the delete operator.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - yes, you can set it to any other value like `undefined` or `""` (an empty string) or `0` and (as long as there are no other references to the data that was in the variable), the garbage collector will free the data.  I generally use `null` in this circumstance and reserve `undefined` for something that hasn't been initialized, but that's more of a programming style issue than one being more correct than the other.

Comment: undefined works differently. But I'm reading article mentioned by DCoder and:
var x = 5;
delete x; // this gives me true (I don't know why);
x; // this gives me "ReferenceError: x is not defined"
And I can't understand how author get false when deleting?

Comment: @FilipGórczyński - just stop trying to use delete on a variable.  It is not supposed to be done.